# Values added to form by jQuery is not received by AngularJS

Tags: jquery, forms, angularjs

I have a form that looks has several input fields. Some of them are populated when the markup is generated. E.g **value=#{ session[:lat] }**  or just **value='111'**
This looks correct when I inspect the page, but this value is not being submitted by Angular.
If I change the input field by hand, then the value is submitted. Is there a way to tell Angular that is input fields will not be updated by humans, but it should still submit the content?

**the markup**

```
 <input id="ad_lat" name="lat" ng-model="ad.lat" value="#{ session[:lat] }"> 
 </input>
```

Best,

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Angular looks at the `ng-model` for the value, not the actual `value` - remove the `value` attribute and set the model on page render:

```
$scope.ad.lat = #{session[:lat];
```

And if you can't do that, use an `init` function and write your server variable there:

```
<div ng-init="init('#{session[:lat]}')">

$scope.init = function(session) {
    $scope.ad.lat = session
}
```